# Story about a criminal who goes from Earth to the Moon to Mars, dragging the government of Earth into space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for name and title of a (short?)story I read long ago.

Premise is someone with space-tech abilities does something nefarious on Earth, and while waiting for the legalities decides to split.  Takes on the Moon, and the governments of the Earth have to catch this guy, then he takes on Mars.  Net result is this guy drags the Earth to the stars....

Comment: The details don't match, but Ben Bova's Sam Gunn stories (in short formats) have a similar flavor.

Comment: At first, I thought "dragging the government" in your title meant the criminal hijacks a spaceship which has the President and his Cabinet (or the equivalent) aboard as passengers, and he literally takes them to the Moon, and then to Mars, despite their screaming objections. But I take it you just mean "he *inspires* the government on Earth to finance building interplanetary spaceships so their *military minions* can chase the guy while the political leaders stay safely home"?

Comment: Ok, 'inspire' might be more to the point, but the story as I remember it was more along the lines of the government being cajoled into chasing this guy down and in the process the expansion of the earths space capabilities is enhanced.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Charles Sheffield's "The Man Who Stole the Moon," but they never got as far as Mars.